# Google Spreadsheet show URL to a new File in pop up window

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am currently trying to show some sort of pop up with a link to a new file that was created in the drive.

let me explain. 
i have a database of employees
my spreadsheet as a button that copies information from a particular employee and then creates and fills another file with his info that then is saved/printed/or exported as pdf.

the script gets the URL of the file after this one is created, but i cant show it in the pop up window as a clickable link. here is my code.
(i am sorry if its a messy code, i learned 1 month ago)

```
 function applicationcreator () {  

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var database = ss.getSheetByName("Database")
var rowname = database.getActiveCell().getRow()
var name = database.getRange(rowname, 4).getValues()
var ss2 = SpreadsheetApp.create("Resume")
var skill = ss2.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
var url =ss2.getUrl()
var form = ss.getSheetByName("Profilegenerator")
var copy = form.copyTo(ss2)
var form2 = ss2.getSheetByName("Copy of Profilegenerator").setName("Resume " + name)

 var htmlOutput = HtmlService
    .createHtmlOutput(url)
    .setWidth(250) //optional
    .setHeight(50); //optional
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(htmlOutput, 'Employee Profile');

}
```

I greatly apreciate your help.

Comment: If my understanding for your question is correct, how about modifying from ``var url =ss2.getUrl()`` to ``var url = '<a href="' + ss2.getUrl() + '" target="_blank">link</a>';``?

Comment: Perfect! that solved my issue! thanks you so much for your help! my program is ready now.

Comment: Welcome. I'm glad your issue was solved.